# UITabBarItem title not displayed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController in which the first UITabBarItem title is not getting displayed.  I have it set in Interface Builder and have tried to set it programmatically, but the title area stays blank.

```
[[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"Test1"];
[[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"Test2"];
```

[image: UITabController view]

(The Item 2 is set through Interface Builder, which is where that title is coming from, just to test that the IB titles are working as well -- except for the first one)

I have a feeling this is the odd result of adding the UITabController to the project and dragging the existing view into the first spot, but don't know how to fix it.

Here's the view in Interface Builder:
[image]

Moving the ViewController that's in the first spot to the second spot yields the result you'd expect -- the second spot becomes blank and the first gets set with "Test1", meaning it's not something funny with just the first spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

type `[self setTitle:@"Title"]` in your viewcontroller for the first view instead of declaring it through the viewcontrollers array. don't know whats wrong though, but I had to do this once

Comment: Great!  That worked -- now, how do I set the image for that UITabBarItem?  It's setting in the NIB isn't being respected either..

Comment: find your tabbaritem in the uitabbarcontroller and put `[tabbaritem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"]]`

Comment: Nope, no luck -- just like the title, the image is ignored.  Which makes me think that solving the initial problem might become necessary.  Darn

Comment: Aight - I have one rule when I decide on using IB or programmatically creating an interface - "Do I need to manually customize this?" cause it's really much easier if you don't include IB's magic :) good luck solving the problem, I'd love to read about it here if you find out what it was

Comment: I was thinking the same thing -- on my to-do list is to branch the project, ditch the IB stuff at least for MainWindow and the UITabController and write it programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

Just go to your init method in your view controller's .m file and in order to set the tab bar item's title use:

```
[[self tabBarItem] setTitle:@"Main"];
```

and for setting its image, use:

```
[[self tabBarItem] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeFilename.png"]];
```